# Dual booting ubuntu 12.04 and windowa 7 on different drives

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I am trying to figure out how to get ubuntu and windows 7 to work in harmony. In essence I want to be able to choose which OS I want to boot. the 2 OS's are currently installed on different hard drives. I have an alienware m14xr1. The optical drive has been removed and I placed a second hard disk in its place using an adapter. I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on the primary hard drive which is a 256Gb SSD. On the secondary drive (in the optical drive position on the board) I have windows installed on a 450gb partition of a 1TB drive. The other partition is going to house my data such as music, photos, videos, movies, etc. Can anyone offer me any guidance on how I can choose what drive I am booting to? Do I need to have both operating systems installed on one drive? Or can I set up something that will allow me to choose which drive I want to boot to? Would this be done in windows or ubuntu? I looked through the bios settings to see if I could find anything. I can choose the boot priority but I can't choose which drive to boot to. When I go into the boot menu on the bios the again I only have the ability to choose hard drive. No option for which drive I want. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't install Ubuntu while your secondary drive with Windows was plugged in, GRUB didn't get a chance to recognize it and thus will only show Ubuntu in its menu.

With the Windows drive plugged in, on Ubuntu, try running `sudo update-grub`. If all goes well, the output should tell you that it found a Linux image (or multiple, it doesn't matter), *and* Windows 7 on your secondary disk (most probably /dev/sdbX, where X is a number, though it could be another letter).

Once it's done, reboot, and make sure the drive with Ubuntu installed is the first one in your boot order. You should then see the GRUB menu with an entry to boot Linux, and another to boot Windows.

If not, you may need to make sure GRUB is set to appear and not timeout too quickly. Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (or any other editor you like, as long as you're sudo'ed), and make sure that both `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` are greater than 0, and that `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` is set to false. Run `sudo update-grub` again and you should be good to go.

As an aside, most BIOS I know allow you to choose which disk to boot to for this boot only. Most of the time it's accomplished by pressing one of the function keys while the computer is booting. Mine is F12, but it can change depending on your BIOS. Of course, the option may not be present at all...